# Angular: factory vs Module pattern

Tags: angularjs, factory, iife, module-pattern

Is there a solid reason one should use factory:

```
app.factory("Items", function() {
...
} );
```

instead of IIFE module pattern:

```
var Items = (function() {
...
}());
```

- there is no need to inject it in controllers etc, it's always available
- I can watch it in console, and I can't do it with factory (or am I wrong?)

I'm sure I would find some other reasons, so what are the benefits in favor of factory?
Thanks

Comment: Keeps stuff out of the global scope.

Comment: But then how are you going to access your IIFE methods inside HTML templates. For example, **ng-click** event. You can access factory methods inside ng-click.

Comment: You don't need `app` even in your globals. :)

Comment: If you want to get your factory `here&now` in your console: `angular.element('[ng-app]').injector().get('Items')`. Sometimes I use `$http` that way :)

Comment: You use encapsulation because you understand the benefits of not leaving junk all over the place where just any code can get its hands on your stuff, plus other benefits like being able to swap out implementations for testing, etc.. If you don't understand that, you may want to start [here](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/). BTW, angular objects should be defined in IIFE's as well, in part to avoid leaving them accessible to the global scope.

Comment: @vp_arth cool, thanks for the tip. As for "app", I don't use it, I see others do. I would use angular.module('app').factory("Items"...

Comment: What is the replacement for Angular modular system in your case? If there is none and your use case is one-file app, using Angular DI is the best choice. It doesn't exclude the possibility of IIFE or named function, but the combination of them will be more verbose and less readable.